# Trapping MySQL Warnings In Python

Tags: python, mysql

I would like to catch and log MySQL warnings in Python. For example, MySQL issues a warning to standard error if you submit `'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS database_of_armaments'` when no such database exists.  I would like to catch this and log it, but even in the try/else syntax the warning message still appears.

The try/except syntax does catch MySQL errors (eg, submission of a typo like `'DRP DATABASE database_of_armaments'`).

I have experimented with `<<except.MySQLdb.Warning>>` -- no luck.  I've looked at the warnings module, but don't understand how to incorporate it into the try/else syntax.

To be concrete, how do I get the following (or something like it) to work.

GIVEN: database 'database_of_armaments' does not exist.

```
try:
    cursor.execute('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS database_of_armaments')
except: <<WHAT DO I PUT HERE?>>
    print 'There was a MySQL warning.' 
    <<AND what goes here if I want to get and manipulate information about the warning?>>
```

UPDATE:

Thanks for the comments.  I had tried these and they didn't work -- but I had been using a DatabaseConnection class that I wrote for a connection, and its runQuery() method to execute.  When I created a connection and cursor outside the class, the try/except Exception caught the "Programming Error", and except MySQLdb.ProgrammingError worked as advertised.

So now I have to figure out what is wrong with my class coding.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I didn't find any of the answers here useful, but http://stackoverflow.com/a/2102315/91238 was.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Follow these steps.

1. Run it with `except Exception, e: print repr(e)`.
2. See what exception you get.
3. Change the `Exception` to the exception you actually got.

Also, remember that the exception, e, is an object.  You can print `dir(e)`, `e.__class__.__name__`, etc.to see what attributes it has.

Also, you can do this interactively at the `>>>` prompt in Python.  You can then manipulate the object directly -- no guessing.

Comment: This helped me, as django helpfully uses the same exception name as the underlying MySQL connector; `OperationalError`.  I switched `from MySQLdb import OperationalError` to `from django.db.utils import OperationalError` at the top of my file, and I was suddenly able to catch the exception.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried something like this?

```
try:
    cursor.execute(some_statement)
except MySQLdb.IntegrityError, e: 
    # handle a specific error condition
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    # handle a generic error condition
except MySQLdb.Warning, e:
    # handle warnings, if the cursor you're using raises them
```

Comment: Though this answer could be more thorough, it's still a better start than the other ones, I don't see why it got downvoted.

Comment: @Flav because warnings don't `raise`

Answer (score 3):

I think the exception you want to catch is a MySQLdb.ProgrammingError, and to get information about it, just add a variable to store the error data (a tuple) in after that i.e:

```
try:
    cursor.execute('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS database_of_armaments')
except MySQLdb.ProgrammingError, e:
    print 'There was a MySQL warning.  This is the info we have about it: %s' %(e)
```

Comment: Don't you mean MySQLdb.OperationalError (instead of ProgrammingError)?

Comment: This is the exception that was being thrown for me in a similar project I'm working on.  And yes I did think it was odd.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to trap the mysql warning like this:

```
import _mysql_exceptions

try:
    foo.bar()
except _mysql_exceptions.Warning, e:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

first you should turn on warnings to treat as exceptions, and only then you can catch them.
see "error" warnings filter - https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter

Comment: And how can I «_turn on warnings to treat as exceptions_» ?

Comment: @freezed added link to related section in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Plain and simple

```
def log_warnings(curs):
    for msg in curs.messages:
        if msg[0] == MySQLdb.Warning:
            logging.warn(msg[1])

cursor.execute('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS database_of_armaments')
log_warnings(cursor)
```

msg[1] example :- `(u'Warning', 1366L, u"Incorrect integer value: '\xa3' for column 'in_userid' at row 1")`