# trapping a MySql warning

Tags: python, mysql

In my python script I would like to trap a "Data truncated for column 'xxx'" warning durnig my query using MySql.

I saw some posts suggesting the code below, but it doesn' work.

Do you know if some specific module must be imported or if some option/flag should be called before using this code?

Thanks all

Afeg

```
import MySQLdb
try:
    cursor.execute(some_statement)
    # code steps always here: No Warning is trapped
    # by the code below
except MySQLdb.Warning, e:
    # handle warnings, if the cursor you're using raises them
except Warning, e:
    # handle warnings, if the cursor you're using raises them
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Warnings are just that: warnings. They get reported to (usually) stderr, but nothing else is done. You can't catch them like exceptions because they aren't being raised.

You can, however, configure what to *do* with warnings, and turn them off or turn them into exceptions, using the `warnings` module. For instance, `warnings.filterwarnings('error', category=MySQLdb.Warning)` to turn `MySQLdb.Warning warnings` into exceptions (in which case they would be caught using your try/except) or `'ignore'` to not show them at all. You can (and probably should) have more fine-grained filters than just the category.

Comment: Hi Thomas. I have just finished to test this code and it works great.
I Thank you very much. I wish you a good evening.
Aeg

Comment: If you want to ignore some specific kind of warnings, use something like `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', 'Unknown table .*')`.

Comment: hi @ThomasWouters, this looks legit... but can you please tell where should we write these `warnings.filterwarnings()` code in for a django project? Do you suggest writing it in every python script where we make a DB insert? Or is there any project wide setting we can use to make this the default behaviour for all kinds of DB inserts in a django app?

Answer (score 15):

Raise MySQL Warnings as errors:

```
import warnings, MySQLdb
warnings.filterwarnings('error', category=MySQLdb.Warning)
```

To ignore instead of raising an error, replace `"error"` with `"ignore"`.

Handle them in a try-except block like:

```
try:
    # a MySQL DB operation that raises a warning
    # for example: a data truncated warning
except Warning as a_warning:
    # do something here
```

Answer (score 5):

I would try first to set the `sql_mode`. You can do this at the session level. If you execute a:

```
SET @@sql_mode:=TRADITIONAL;
```

(you could also set it at the server level, but you need access to the server to do that. and, that setting an still be overridden at the session level, so the bottom line is, always set it at the session level, immediately after establishing the connection)

then many things that are normally warnings become errors. I don't know how those manifest themselves at the python level, but the clear advantage is that the changes are not stored in the database. See: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_traditional](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_traditional)

Comment: Cool! I didn't know all that stuff related to SQL!

Comment: Is this set on a "connection" level or a "cursor" level? Because I've tried setting this both as the keyword argument [`sql_mode` in the `connect` function](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#functions-and-attributes), as well as executing it right after opening the connection, but I still just get warnings.

Comment: @Hubro should be connection level. Have you tried SELECT @@sql_mode to see if the TRADITIONAL mode took effect? The value returned should include everything listed here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_traditional

Answer (score 5):

If you want to trap it to ignore it see "Temporarily suppressing warnings" in Python's documentation:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    # Put here your query raising a warning
```

Else, just read the doc about "warnings" module of Python, you can transform them into exception if you want to catch them later, etc... it's all here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to Thomas Wouters reply, there is no need to import the warnings module to turn them into errors. Just run your script with "-W error" (or ignore) as flag for Python.

Comment: The most complete answer was this point along with @Thomas' accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using MySQL's [SHOW WARNINGS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-warnings.html) command?

Comment: Hi nosklo. Thanks! I need to test it. because it seems to me that it is more useful on SQL client side than on my python script.
I will get back to you asap and thanks AFeG

Answer (score 2):

Stop using MySQLdb. It has such stupid behavior as truncating data and issuing only a warning. Use [oursql](https://launchpad.net/oursql) instead.

Comment: I do queries directly in SQL with MySQL and still get "Warning: Truncated incorrect....". Then maybe we should stop using MySQL instead and use PostgreSQL. Oh, how I wish I could!