# How can I inform sqlalchemy to raise an error whenever MySQL throws a warning?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, warnings, mysql-python

I want to modify sqlalchemy settings to raise an exception on warnings.

For example, when I insert a larger amount of data in a field than the defined column length, mysql will truncate the data, insert the truncated data into the field and issue a warning.

Instead of the warning, I would like sqlalchemy to raise an appropriate error on behalf of mysql.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102251/trapping-a-mysql-warning

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To turn the “oh by the way I mangled your data” warnings into errors, 
set an appropriate [server mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) for MySQL.
With SQLAlchemy, you should choose ANSI, as you probably don't have to worry about your old queries being compatible with some *<s>broken</s>*MySQL-specific behavior.

See the [SQLAlchemy docs](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/dialects/mysql.html#sql-mode) on how to do it.

---

(Also consider using a database that's strict by default. [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/) comes to mind.)