# Python - How to catch specific mysql warnings?

Tags: python, try-catch, warnings, mysql-python

I want to catch any warning that contains the string 'value'.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102251/trapping-a-mysql-warning/2102315#2102315), I see this example to catch a specific message:

```
warnings.filterwarnings('error', 'Unknown table .*')
```

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warning-filter) say about the message parameter:

> message is a string containing a regular expression that the warning message must match (the match is compiled to always be case-insensitive).

I have the following code but no errors are thrown and instead I'm just getting the warnings which I cannot catch.

```
warnings.filterwarnings('error', message='\bvalue\b')
```

What am I missing? As far as I know, that regex should work for matching the 'value' string.

Answer (score 0):

Python's regular expression syntax is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), and the first thing it says is:

> Regular expressions use the backslash character ('\') to indicate special forms or to allow special characters to be used without invoking their special meaning. This collides with Python’s usage of the same character for the same purpose in string literals; for example, to match a literal backslash, one might have to write '\\' as the pattern string, because the regular expression must be \, and each backslash must be expressed as \ inside a regular Python string literal.
>
> The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in a string literal prefixed with 'r'. So r"\n" is a two-character string containing '\' and 'n', while "\n" is a one-character string containing a newline. Usually patterns will be expressed in Python code using this raw string notation.

In Python, as in many languages, the string `'\b'` corresponds to ASCII backspace
([link](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)).

You need to escape your backslash characters, or else use Python's special "raw/regex" prefix:

```
warnings.filterwarnings('error', message='\\bvalue\\b')
warnings.filterwarnings('error', message=r'\bvalue\b')
```

Comment: Tried both, still not working.  The following will catch the warnings although it's not as specific as I want, hence the question: warnings.filterwarnings('error', category=MySQLdb.Warning).  This is the warning: /Users/jeff/Dropbox/homedev/fundlookup/data/db.py:35: Warning: Field 'crd' doesn't have a default value