# MYSQLdb/Python Value error but still getting desired result

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have written a piece of code in python, which uses the mySQLdb module to search a database for dates within a given month. I'm getting the results i want but i'm also getting an error message which. I believe its because of the wildcard in the date field but i'm failing to understand how it can be wrong and still return the records.

```
def GetWeeks(self):
        guiAction = guiConnections()
        #creates the DBconnection as a tuple, with cursor as index [0]
        DBcon = DBconnect()
        self.Month = "09"
        self.Year = "2015"
        #Creates the SQL statement with the DBsearch function
        self.WeekSearch = DBsearch((self.Year)+"-"+(self.Month)+"-"+"__", ("Date"),Keyword = "LIKE")
        DBcon[0].execute(self.WeekSearch)
        c = DBcon[0].fetchall()
        for row in c:
            print row
    GetWeeks(self)
```

above is the main function, the DBsearch goes to another file with a generic SQL select statement in. The Date field is set to a "Date" type.

```
SELECT * FROM `Timesheet`
WHERE `Date` LIKE "2015-09-%"
```

this is the SQL select statement that gets passed through, and it returns all the records im after but it also returns

Warning: Incorrect date value: '2015-09-%' for column 'Date' at row 1
  DBcon[0].execute(self.WeekSearch)

I don't think the code itself is the problem(albeit messy and a bit rough) im just unsure how to remove this error, or step around it.

i cant find any other threads that relate to wildcards in date formatted field errors, 
Happy to provide more info
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior has been spotted already by others [*from what*](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38915) [**it seems**](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61216). Generally since this is a `Warning` there should be much reason for concern but if they are bugging you you [can always supress them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102251/trapping-a-mysql-warning).

As a necessity for pointing to urls that might become unavailable at some point, a suggested solution by the first bug issued is, and I copy:

> **Suggested fix:**
>
> Make MySQL not raise warnings for char/datetime mismatch when doing a LIKE query.
>
> A temporary fix is to rewrite the query like so:
>
> mysql> `select * from t where cast(d as char) like '2010-01-%';`

Comment: So to my understanding its simply because i'm asking SQL to search data in date format, as string? The bug report does suggest that removing this warning is the suggested fix their end, and i am getting the results i want from the search so i think i'l just ignore it for now. Thanks

Comment: That's what I'm understanding. Either way, most agree it does not affect the results returned so supressing it is a safe solution.