# Not warn INSERT IGNORE python

Tags: python, mysql, duplicates, sql-insert

Is there any way to not raise any warning when using `INSERT IGNORE` ?

I am getting this warning from my python script and I would like not to show it since this warning is expected (that is why I use `IGNORE`):

> Warning: Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'BOUND_APPLICATION'

Comment: What is the context. IE: Why can;t you just ignore it ! (excuse the pun)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102251/trapping-a-mysql-warning) question

Comment: @FrankerZ thanks!  that is what I was looking for